# NetBeans Apache not recognising MySQL server

Tags: mysql, netbeans, server, setup-project

I'm trying to open a web project on NetBeans Apache and for that I need to select a server. I downloaded a mySQL server and in MySQL workbench it says the server is running, but whenever I try to add the server in NetBeans it doesn't show up as an option. I do have the databases setup using the connecter in NetBeans but for some reason i cant setup the server which I need to do to open the web project.
MySQL workbench:[enter image description here][1]

The database:[enter image description here][2]

[enter image description here][3]

Whenever I try to add the server:[enter image description here][4]

Sorry, im new to this so I pretty don't know anything
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiJ9p.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4Eab.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/asc2w.jpg
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOZmo.jpg

Comment: [1] You may be misunderstanding how to get your web project set up. You need to add your web project to an _application server_ (e.g. Tomcat, GlassFish, etc.) rather than a _database service_ (e.g. MySQL). [2] So in your screen shot tagged _"[4]"_, select the application server that you plan to use (e.g. Tomcat, GlassFish) and click "Next>" to complete the creation of your application server instance. Then you can add your web project to that server. [3] There is nothing in your screen shots to indicate any problem - you just need to complete the process. [4] Use screen shots, not photos.

Comment: Ahh, alright thank you. Does that mean I'll have to download a tomcat/glassfish server and get it running or can that be done through NetBeans?

Comment: Yes, you will need to download and install an application server, and yes, that can be done through NetBeans. Having selected an Application server (e.g. Payara) in your _"Add Server Instance"_ screen shot , NetBeans will invite you to select a version to download (using the _Download Now..._ button). Then, once your application server is installed you can build web project and deploy it to that application server.